# Why is apt-get randomly checking for non-existent resources?

Tags: apt

I have an automated script which, among other tasks, updates the sources with `apt-get update` and then installs additional packages through `apt-get install`.

Occasionally (10—20% of the time), `apt-get update` fails with the following errors:

> init[356]: W: Failed to fetch http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/source/Sources  404  Not Found
>   init[356]: E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Indeed, the browser shows that the referenced file doesn't exist: [the corresponding directory](http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/source/) contains only the following files:

- `Release`
- `Sources.gz`
- `Sources.xz`

The `stdout` from such failed `apt-get update` is this one:

```
Get:1 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease [63.1 kB]
Ign http://http.us.debian.org jessie InRelease
Get:2 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Sources [160 kB]
Get:3 http://http.us.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease [142 kB]
Get:4 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages [302 kB]
Get:5 http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Translation-en [161 kB]
Hit http://http.us.debian.org jessie Release.gpg
Get:6 http://http.us.debian.org jessie-updates/main Sources [15.5 kB]
Get:7 http://http.us.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex [5,440 B]
Get:8 http://http.us.debian.org jessie-updates/main Translation-en/DiffIndex [2,704 B]
Hit http://http.us.debian.org jessie Release
Get:9 http://http.us.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [6,761 kB]
Get:10 http://http.us.debian.org jessie/main Translation-en [4,580 kB]
Err http://http.us.debian.org jessie/main Sources
  404  Not Found
Fetched 12.2 MB in 28s (433 kB/s)
```

The two last HTTP requests being:

```
http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/i18n/Translation-en.bz2
http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/source/Sources
```

By comparison, here's `apt-get update` ran manually from the same machine after the original one failed:

```
Ign http://http.us.debian.org jessie InRelease
Get:1 http://http.us.debian.org jessie-updates InRelease [142 kB]
Get:2 http://http.us.debian.org jessie Release.gpg [2,373 B]              
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates InRelease
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Sources
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main amd64 Packages
Get:3 http://http.us.debian.org jessie-updates/main amd64 Packages/DiffIndex [5,440 B]
Hit http://security.debian.org jessie/updates/main Translation-en
Get:4 http://http.us.debian.org jessie-updates/main Translation-en/DiffIndex [2,704 B]
Get:5 http://http.us.debian.org jessie Release [148 kB]
Get:6 http://http.us.debian.org jessie-updates/main Sources [15.5 kB]
Get:7 http://http.us.debian.org jessie/main Sources [7,057 kB]
Get:8 http://http.us.debian.org jessie/main amd64 Packages [6,761 kB]
Get:9 http://http.us.debian.org jessie/main Translation-en [4,580 kB]
Fetched 18.7 MB in 12s (1,557 kB/s)                                            
Reading package lists... Done
```

and the three URIs corresponding to the `Get:7` to `Get:9`:

```
http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/source/Sources.xz
http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/binary-amd64/Packages.xz
http://http.us.debian.org/debian/dists/jessie/main/i18n/Translation-en.bz2
```

Why is `apt-get update` occasionally figuring out that it should download `Sources.xz`, while other times trying to get the missing `Sources`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download xz (or gz) compressed listfiles from everywhere

```
echo 'Acquire::CompressionTypes::Order:: { "xz"; "gz"; };' > /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/47compress
```